# Why WNetOpenEnum gets ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS (487) result?

Tags: winapi, rust

trying to rewrite using WINAPI library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/enumerating-network-resources on Rust

```
let dw_result: DWORD;
let mut h_enum: LPHANDLE = null_mut();
let mut lpnr_local: LPNETRESOURCEW = null_mut();


dw_result = WNetOpenEnumW(RESOURCE_GLOBALNET, // all network resources
                          RESOURCETYPE_ANY,   // all resources
                          0,  // enumerate all resources
                          lpnr_local,       // NULL first time the function is called
                          h_enum);
if dw_result != WN_NO_ERROR {
     println!("WnetOpenEnum failed with error {:?}\n", dw_result);
}
```

But this code assign 487 into dw_result which means ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS

And I can't get what is wrong

Comment: The final argument to `WNetOpenEnumW` needs to be a pointer to a value of type `HANDLE`, yet you are passing a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your doubt is the difference between `LPHANDLE` and `HANDLE`.

> LP stands for Long Pointer. It's a pointer to a handle.

If you want to use `LPHANDLE`, please give it a legal address。

Like this:(C++)

```
HANDLE ph;
LPHANDLE hEnum = &ph;
```

Or simply use `HANDLE`.

```
let mut h_enum: HANDLE;
...
dw_result = WNetOpenEnumW(RESOURCE_GLOBALNET, // all network resources
                      RESOURCETYPE_ANY,   // all resources
                      0,  // enumerate all resources
                      lpnr_local,       // NULL first time the function is called
                      &h_enum);
```

Related: [LPHANDLE vs. HANDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391649/lphandle-vs-handle)

Comment: @Xuyne Oni Hi, if the answer is useful to you, don't forget to mark it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)